# How to save and recreate layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am currently working on Android app which is like a simpler version of Photoshop in functionality.

So, I created a CustomView called DragAndDropContainer which handles all the drag and drop operations. The user can drag other CustomViews in it like Text, etc.

The problem is that whenever user clicks on Done, I want to save the layout and restore it later on when user reopens the app.

I researched and I was not able to find the best way to save and restore a layout. The DragAndDropContainer is a CustomView where user can drag anywhere, so I need to understand how to implement a method to save its final state and restore later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use any local database like Realm or Room DB to save the list of custom views and then load it from db whenever user come back to the screen.

Comment: You sound right @deepakkumar. However, do you have any tips on how to save the customview locations? The issue is that if i store it in pixels, it wont scale well on different variety of devices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can convert the pixels to dp before you save it

Comment: Exactly! Can't believe I forgot about this. Thanks @HB.